# How to call docker-compose down within a container?

Tags: docker, flask, docker-compose, containers

I have different services defined in my docker-compose.yml file, and one of them is a gateway. The gateway service is a Flask app with a few endpoints for messages, states and state transitions. I want to stop the system (docker-compose down) automatically when the state is SHUTDOWN (can be done via http PUT request with SHUTDOWN as body), but I'm not sure how to do that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can install docker/docker-compose in a docker container and then mount the docker daemon into the container:

```
docker run -it -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock ubuntu:latest sh -c "apt-get update ; apt-get install docker.io -y ; bash"
```

[see here](https://forums.docker.com/t/how-can-i-run-docker-command-inside-a-docker-container/337)

Comment: Remember that anyone who has the Docker socket can all but trivially root the entire host.  Consider whether "it'd be nice to remotely stop the application" actually justifies this level of security exposure.